# proptypes on array of shape, number or string

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to create propTypes for an optional prop that can be a string, number or an object with certain properties.

This is what I have tried:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
filter: PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.shape({
    deviceId: PropTypes.number,
    deviceType: PropTypes.string,
    firmware: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    serialNumber: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  PropTypes.string,
  PropTypes.number,
])
```

This doesn't give out any errors regardless of prop-value. I can give any value for the filter. It can be a boolean or an array with no complaints.
I also would like to limit the possible properties to the ones listed above.
Any idea what's wrong and how to get it to work?

Comment: "The only way it gives an error is if I put"  - seems that the end of post is missing

Comment: I think the prop type check only give a warning in development mode. it will not stop the application running if the prop type is not matched. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Looks like an other editorial mistake left over from question v.1. removing that last line.